# Gematria of Person's Name

Tags: gematria-numerology

Kol Hator states that a person has multiple gematrios that are important to him, such as one's name, one's name plus father's  name, name plus father's and mother's name, etc, etc.

My question is, when doing the main name, that simple. However, when adding any of the others, should a person add the word ben (son of) or just the names next to each other, and even more, what about multiple names, should they include a vav such as "ben Abraham "u'ben" Sarah.

Comment: I haven't read Kol Hator so I don't know if it specifies, but I don't know if you are aware that there are also multiple different systems of how to calculate the value of each word.  Perhaps some of it is subjective - if you feel that you take particular koach from a specific parent (eg. because you are proud to take after them in a certain way) then it makes more sense to include their name?

Comment: @user25501 can you please cite exactly where the text states that, and which edition you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Depends who's counting the gematria and I assume it is how ever that person is commonly called, though it sounds like the KH you quoted does not include ben or bat. But I can tell you an unusual example known in Breslev world so for example in the Foreword to L. Moharan "לכו חזו" the author instead of invoking the usual "bar" calls Rashbi Rabbi Shimon ben Yochai = 466 + 35 apparently to make the gematria נחמן בן שמחה = 148 + 353.
Both total 501, without the Ben, among the other amazing word plays there.
I think the idea is 501 is ראש.

By the way if you like Mispar Katan it looks like when you add Ben Abraham you add 21, AKYK.
And adding Ben Sarah adds 17, TOB.

If you add Nanach as in Nissim Nanach you add 18, Chai!